# How can i change the "Composer.lock" file version or get the flySystem-google-drive:~1.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php, flysystem-google-drive

[composer require nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive:~1.1"]  ["I also tried many other commands for solving the error but they didn't work out so these are some commands I used   "composer update", "composer install", "composer dump-autoload"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnYPB.png)

Comment: Most probably you have to downgrade `league/flysystem`. But, this package was last updated in 2020, Are you sure you want to use that?

Comment: yes because I want to connect with google drive and dropbox at the same time and manage both backup files at the same time. so for that I need the flysystem package.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion given by Composer with the error message (`--with-all-dependencies`)?

Comment: yes I tried it.